# Advanced Installer Web package "Cannot access URL"

Tags: advanced-installer

I'm trying create a Web Installer using Advanced Installer 18.5.

For the MSI's URL I've put

file://192.168.11.33/RepositoryStaging/Mytest/Install.msi

However when I try to run the installer, I get the following error:

> Cannot access URL: file://192.168.11.33/RepositoryStaging/Mytest/Install.msi

I have copied the MSI and all the other files (except the exe) created by Advanced Installer to that location, and when I paste the same URL into my browser, it downloads the MSI no problem.

What is the issue here? Perhaps does it not work with the `file://` prefixes or using IP addresses?

The [page on the subject on their website](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/qa-web-installation.html) doesn't seem to shine any light on this.

Comment: It seems to be a bug related to accessing resources from a local network. Have you tried using an HTTP(S) url?

Comment: You can try to create a log for your EXE setup by launching it with a command line like this: "setup/exe /exelog log.txt" and maybe the log file exposes more details about the MSI access error.

Also, if your EXE setup is launched elevated (e.g. using "Run as admin" option) can you make sure your user account running elevated can access the MSI URL? For instance you can launch your web browser elevated and try to access the MSI URL and make sure this works.